# Show tooltip when dragging node in TreeViewAdv

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

When dragging a node, although I get the Move icon there is no tooltip text shown in my case as there is in the given SimpleExample, using Andrey Gliznetsov's [TreeViewAdv](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14741/Advanced-TreeView-for-NET).

This doesn't seem to be affected by adding a Tooltip object and using SetToolTip method. How do I get the tooltip to show the text (and icon) of the dragged node when dragging?

[image: SimpleExample showing tooltip]
[image: Cursor changed but no tooltip]]

Answer (score 0):

In TreeViewAdv.Input.cs, you will find this method

```
private void CreateDragBitmap(IDataObject data)
    {
        if (UseColumns || !DisplayDraggingNodes)
            return;
```

which prevents a _dragBitmap being created if columns are being used. If you have to use the TreeViewAdv control dll without modification, then the only workaround if you want to see the tooltip is to not use columns (Property UseColumns = False).

But since the source code is provided, you could modify CreateDragBitmap by removing the condition UseColumns from the first if statement in this method and adding a condition inside the foreach NodeControl loop to exit after the first is drawn:

```
private void CreateDragBitmap(IDataObject data)
    {
        if (!DisplayDraggingNodes) //removed UseColumns as OR condition here
            return;

        TreeNodeAdv[] nodes = data.GetData(typeof(TreeNodeAdv[])) as TreeNodeAdv[];
        if (nodes != null && nodes.Length > 0)
        {
            Rectangle rect = DisplayRectangle;
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);
            using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                gr.Clear(BackColor);
                DrawContext context = new DrawContext();
                context.Graphics = gr;
                context.Font = Font;
                context.Enabled = true;
                int y = 0;
                int maxWidth = 0;
                foreach (TreeNodeAdv node in nodes)
                {
                    if (node.Tree == this)
                    {
                        int x = 0;
                        int height = _rowLayout.GetRowBounds(node.Row).Height;
                        foreach (NodeControl c in NodeControls)
                        {
                            Size s = c.GetActualSize(node, context);
                            if (!s.IsEmpty)
                            {
                                int width = s.Width;
                                rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
                                x += (width + 1);
                                context.Bounds = rect;
                                c.Draw(node, context);
                                if (UseColumns) //only show first column if using columns
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        y += height;
                        maxWidth = Math.Max(maxWidth, x);
                    }
                }

                if (maxWidth > 0 && y > 0)
                {
                    _dragBitmap = new Bitmap(maxWidth, y, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                    using (Graphics tgr = Graphics.FromImage(_dragBitmap))
                        tgr.DrawImage(bitmap, Point.Empty);
                    BitmapHelper.SetAlphaChanelValue(_dragBitmap, 150);
                }
                else
                    _dragBitmap = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

which results in

[image: Cursor changed and first column as tooltip]

If you wanted to see all columns when dragging, omit the `if (UseColumns) break;` change, which looks like this

[image: Cursor changed and all columns in tooltip]